# How can I get an overview of realtime dataset?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, cluster-sample

Can I use some part of the real time dataset for  getting an overview about the dataset before applying an algorithm? Can I use `ELKI` or `R` software for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

**Always** get some sample data first, and *visualize the heck out of it*. Use ELKI, R, SciPy, Matlab, ... whatever you are confident with.

First you need to understand your problem and your data, then you can start solving the problem.

Comment: I have one more question regarding per-modelling or data prediction? Do i need any any data-cleaning process before using ELKI, R or WEKA tool or i can directly use my :CSV file directly on software. Actually i am student and and i have to use twitter and flickr realtime data but my teacher give me  instruction that i have to see the data and evaluate the data statistically and graphically to see the no of clusters on dataset and on the behalf of result i will use algorithm. I am not from this field that's why i am fuzzy to solve the problem?

Comment: Usually, preprocessing and filtering your data is 90% of the work. These tools will have some functionality, but maybe not all you need, so you will need to write some additional filters.

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the data real time is probably the best way to get an overview of the data before applying any complicated algorithms. You can do this using the plot function in R. If you have data coming in live, you can select the $n$ most recent observations and plot them. If you write a script that updates automatically, this will give you a moving window idea about how the data is moving.

Many other data exploration options exist, but plotting the data is one of the most fundamental practices in [Exploratory Data Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis).